# Where does django output csv file?

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm new to Django and new to web programming in general. I'm trying to export my data in the database into csv file. I've tried "Using the python csv library" in this link : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/

```
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse

def some_view(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
    writer.writerow(['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])

    return response
```

Where can I find the somefilename.csv file? I want it to be in my application folder. So, tt returns HttpResponse object. Do I need to do something with it to get the csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code you are writing the csv to the HTTP response, so it'll show up in the users browser. The file is never created locally.

The client's browser knows that the response should be saved with the `somefilename.csv` filename since that's the header you're sending, but again, the file is never created locally on the server.

Comment: Oh, ok. Then, I guess this is not a way to go. Is there any convenient way to create csv on the local server? If not, I think I need to go back to SELECT OUTFILE INTO query.